# How to extract an object tag from a text

Tags: php, html

Hi
I've created a system that adds articles in the database, the user can embed youtube or dailymotion or simple flash into the text area. In the home page, I've inserted a slideshow that slides new feed with image, I've writen a simple condition if that checks if the text contains an embeded video using:

```
if (ereg('<object>',$text){}
```

I just want to insert the video(object element in general) in the slide show in case there's an object in the text. in other words I want to extract what's between `<object>` and `</object>`

thank you

Comment: Bare in mind that `ereg` is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @ncuesta but what does this mean if it's deprecated of PHP 5.3.0

Comment: it means that in future releases of PHP the function will be removed, and your code won't be valid anymore. In this particular case, it is adviced to drop `ereg()` for `preg_match()`: http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php

Comment: @ncuesta , thank you my friend , I will remove it from my code +1 for your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the slideshow part or if you are also trying to modify the content. But for the extraction part there's two options. You can use a simple-minded regular expression like:

```
preg_match("#<object[^>]*>(.+?)</object>#ims", $text, $matches);
print $matches[1];
```

Or a more reliable HTML parser with a readable API like phpQuery or [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/):

```
print qp($text)->find("object")->text();
```

The latter would also allow you to extract attributes more easily.